# Delete the maximum ID row

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I find duplicate rows and for each group of duplicate rows delete the max ID row, in MySQL?

Using this query, I can find duplicate rows:

```
SELECT * , COUNT( awb_no ) c
FROM tbl_cod_rpt_COPY
GROUP BY awb_no
HAVING c >1
```

And this query gives me the maximum ID for each group:

```
SELECT * , MAX( tbl_cod_rpt_id )
FROM tbl_cod_rpt_COPY
GROUP BY awb_no
HAVING COUNT( awb_no ) >1
```

Now how would I delete the `tbl_cod_rpt_COPY` rows matching the `MAX( tbl_cod_rpt_id )` values from the query above?

Comment: it delete all duplicate record but i need to  remove last added duplicate record

Comment: Even when there are say 12 rows withe the same `awb_no`, you want to remove the last one and keep the previous 11 intact?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: Then it should be quite trivial to modify the queries in the linked answer to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL allows a join in a `DELETE` statement. You can use this feature to first get a derived table, similar to the query you have that finds all maximum ids for groups that have more than 1 row, then join this derived table to the table itself.

The following assumes that `(tbl_cod_rpt_id)` is the primary key of the table:

```
DELETE 
    t.*
FROM 
    ( SELECT awb_no, MAX(tbl_cod_rpt_id) AS tbl_cod_rpt_id
      FROM tbl_cod_rpt_COPY
      GROUP BY awb_no
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS dup
JOIN 
    tbl_cod_rpt_COPY AS t
  ON 
    t.tbl_cod_rpt_id = dup.tbl_cod_rpt_id ;
```